# How can I access self.data['my_field_here']

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework. in my Serializer's create function (shown below), I print self. The output (also shown below) includes the field self.data['is_barber'].

How can I access the value of that field?

Any time I try to access self.data, I get 'Python recursion limit reached' error..

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_barber = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('email', 'password', 'id', 'token', 'is_barber')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
        read_only_fields = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_barber')

    def get_token(self, validated_data):
        email = str(validated_data)
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)

        return token.key

    def get_is_barber(self, validated_data):
        print 'SELF:'
        print self

        email = str(validated_data)
        user = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)

        return profile.is_barber

    def create(self, validated_data, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Create and return a new User instance, given the validated data.
        """

        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        email = validated_data.pop('email', None)

        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        if email is not None:
            instance.username = email.lower()
            instance.email = email.lower()
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

Result of printing SELF:

self

```
UserSerializer(context={u'view': <barbers.views.UserList object>, u'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object>, u'format': None}, data={u'password': u'pass', u'is_barber': u'True', u'email': u'beeeastly@gmail.com'}):
    email = EmailField(allow_blank=True, label='Email address', max_length=254, required=False)
    password = CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True)
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    token = SerializerMethodField()
    is_barber = SerializerMethodField()
```

How can I access self.data['is_barber']??

Comment: instead of `print self` try `print self.__dict__`

Comment: Thanks @Alexander!!!! I can access **is_barber** value with `is_barber = self.__dict__['initial_data']['is_barber']`

Comment: What does `self.initial_data['is_barber']` return?

Comment: self.initial_data['is_barber'] also works! I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Notice how close the solution is to your initial question.

Comment: yeah, at least I know I was moving in the right direction.   I'm still new enough to Django that some of its magic is still working against me.